# Print the last longest string PYTHON

Tags: python

I'm currently facing the problem of not being able to print the last longest string.
Strings example:

```
banica
pizza
kiufte
```

The first and the third are same length, but I want the last longest string.

```
def longest(list1):
    longest_list = max(len(elem) for elem in list1)
    return longest_list
somelist=[]
while True:

    s = input()

    if s == "END":
        break
    somelist.append(s)
longest_string = max(somelist, key=len)
print(longest_string)
```

Comment: What is the "last" longest string? Do you mean that, out of a list if strings, you want the string with the greatest index in the list that shares its length with the longest string?

Answer (score 5):

I don`t know, what exactly you are trying to achieve, but as

```
longest_string = max(somelist, key=len)
```

gives you the first element with max length, you can just reverse the list, and get the last:

```
longest_string = max(somelist[::-1], key=len)
```

Comment: As stated in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max `If multiple items are maximal, the function returns the first one encountered.` Simple and neat solution!

Answer (score 0):

This will work as you want :

```
    def longest(list1):
    longest_list = max(len(elem) for elem in list1)
    return longest_list
somelist=[]
while True:

    s = input()

    if s == "END":
        break
    somelist.append(s)
longest_string = max(somelist[::-1], key=len)
print(longest_string)
```

Comment: **1.** Syntax error. **2.** Superfluous function `longest()`. **3.** No difference between your solution and the Ni3dzwi3dz's one, answered 15 minutes earlier than you.

Answer (score 0):

To employ your `longest()` function:

```
longest_length = longest(somelist)
longest_string = [s for s in somelist if len(s) == longest_length][-1]
```

(Index `[-1]` extracts the *last* element.)